Ошибка: sqlite3.OperationalError: incomplete input
Мой код:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):

    conn = sqlite3.connect('child_base.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS register (id int auto_increment primary key, name varchar(500), date_birth varchar(500), musical_Genre varchar(500), author varchar(500), hobby varchar(500), motive varchar(500), school varchar(500))')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет. Регистрация, Введите имя')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)

def user_name(message):
        global Name
        Name = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите Вашу Дату Рождения(Пример: дд.мм.гг. 20.01.2024) ')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_date)

def user_date(message):
    global date_of_birth
    date_of_birth = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Музыку каких жанров вы предпочитаете (Пример: Рок, Попса, Рэп, Метал, ХэвиМетал, Трэп')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_genre)

def user_genre(message):
    global Genre
    Genre = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Круто!')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'А каких исполнителей ты слушаешь?(Будет круто, если ты напишешь точь в точь. Например: ANNA ASTI, КИНО, БИ-2')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_author)

def user_author(message):
    global Author
    Author = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши чем ты еще занимался или занимаешься по мимо гитары( Пример: Бокс 2 года, Лыжи 2 месяца, Шахматы 7 лет')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_hobby)

def user_hobby(message):
    global Hobby
    Hobby = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Почему ты решил научиться играть на гитаре? Например: "Я хочу стать душой компании", "Я хочу выступать на сцене", "Хочу стать рокером", "Просто захотелось"')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_motive)

# Это последний этап регистрации здесь все переменные о правляются в базу данных Sql
def user_motive(message):
    global Motive
    Motive = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'И последний вопрос. где ты сейчас учишься? (Например: "школа номер 8, 5 класс", "САХГУ, 2-ой курс"')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_school)



def user_school(message):
    global Schcool
    Schcool = message.text
    conn = sqlite3.connect('child_base.db')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(f'INSERT INTO register (name, date_birth, musical_Genre, author, hobby, motive, school) VALUES ("{Name}", "{date_of_birth}", "{Genre}", "{Author}", "{Hobby}", "{Motive}", "{School}"')
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    # markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список пользователей', callback_data='users'))
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Сохранить Данные', callback_data='register'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Отлично осталось только сохраниться', reply_markup=markup)


Вы делаете бота для одного человека? Зачем тогда бот, сделайте консольное приложение. Ну и неплохо было бы питон выучить, а потом уже в ботов лезть

Бот, для большого количества учеников, чтобы автоматизировать сбор данных для Аналитики.

С глобалами он только для одного участника, переменная то одна на всех.
